# How to reference a file in specific repo & branch in Azure pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

**So - I have a pipeline that checks out a template from another repo:**

`pipelineTemplates/copyDockerImage.yml@template-repo`

It works fine.

But I created a new branch `333-new-file` in `template-repo` with alternate version of the `copyDockerImage.yml` file.

Now I want my pipeline to use the new file that's still in my `333-new-file` branch. Simply I want to test the file before I will merge it.

I tried `pipelineTemplates/copyDockerImage.yml@template-repo/333-new-file` but this only get's me an error:

pipelineTemplates/copyDockerImage.yml: No repository found by name template-repo/333-new-file
pipelineTemplates/copyDockerImage.yml: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**How to make pipeline use my new file ?**

----------- UPDATE -------------

My jobs file:

```
parameters:
  - name: environment
    type: string

jobs:
  - job: createDockerImage
    displayName: Create new Docker image
    pool: $(buildAgentPoolLinux)

    steps:
      - script: |
          echo "my script"

      - template: path/to/copyDockerImage.yml@template-repo
        parameters:
          par1: string1
```

------------------- UPDATE 2 -------------------

`createDockerImage` "steps" file:

```
parameters:
  - name: dependsOn # Job depends on other devops job(s)
    type: object
    default:

steps:

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Generate tag name
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscriptionName }}
      scriptType: pscore
      failOnStandardError: true
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        # script here

 - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Copy image
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscriptionName }}
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      scriptType: pscore
      inlineScript: |
        # second script here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out a specific ref using the `ref` property when you define the repositories resources.

Example yaml for Step reuse:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: template-repo
    type: git
    name: testproject/testrepo
    ref: refs/heads/333-new-file

parameters:
  - name: environment
    type: string


jobs:
  - job: createDockerImage
    displayName: Create new Docker image
    pool: $(buildAgentPoolLinux)
    steps:
      - script: |
          echo "my script"
      - template: path/to/copyDockerImage.yml@template-repo
        parameters:
          dependsOn: 'test'
```

For more details, please refer [Use other repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-extends#use-other-repositories) and [Checking out a specific ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checking-out-a-specific-ref).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Take a look at my updated question - I added my complete jobs file. When I put resources section anywhere before `Jobs` I get  `copyDockerImage.yml (Line: 12, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'jobs'
/copyDockerImage.yml: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` When I put it between `pool` and `steps` I get `Unexpected value resources` and `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`. **Where should I put the `resources` section then ?**

Comment: Hi @Wojtek_B, it seems in your `copyDockerImage.yml`, there is a job and it is a job reuse template. So, the template cannot be placed in steps of the 'createDockerImage' job. I have updated the answer with the new yaml.  If you want to only use one job, you can consider to use [Step reuse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#step-reuse).

Comment: In my case the `path/to/copyDockerImage.yml` contains additional steps - I can't change this file. I will update my question with the file's general structure. But in essence steps in template file are a part (and have to be) of the `createDockerImage` job.

Comment: Hi,  @Wojtek_B,  I updated the answer for Step reuse. It works in my pipeline. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: my pipeline looks exactly as in you reply (branch name is of course different) but I'm still getting `copyDockerImage.yml (Line: 12, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'jobs'...

Comment: Hi @Wojtek_B, can you make sure if the `copyDockerImage.yml` file contains the `jobs` and check the Line: 12 again?  If there are no jobs in `copyDockerImage.yml`, this error would be too strange.

Comment: My pipeline `copyDockerImage.yml` is a part of another one - and the resource were actually already defined "one level" up in the main pipeline. I added `ref` definition and it worked. Thanks !